Finding the equation for a curve contained within a larger tan function.
I am currently trying to find a function describing a curve contained within the domain [0.5, infinity] and the range [1, infinity] shown in the picture below.
The larger function is defined by the equation f(x) = xtan(1/x). The challenge is to find a (presumably simpler equation) describing the outlined section alone. I do not know any methods of tackling this problem and I would appreciate any advice.
Visual of the tan function with smaller curve contained within asymptote lines.
I have tried using a taylor series centred around x = 1, however due to the nature of the tan equation this process became complicated before I was able to discern any useful patterns in the taylor series that would hint at the nature of a function that may describe the smaller curve.
Thanks.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
